# Implementing dynamic component collection switching in next.js with optional URL change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, radix-ui

I have multiple component collections, each with a different style but sharing the same interface. I aim to develop a page in Next.js where users can switch between these component collections, with the option for the URL to change accordingly. How can I achieve this dynamic component collection switching functionality in Next.js?

Due to the stark differences in style among each collection, utilizing CSS variables to define a theme is unfeasible.

Any insights, suggestions, or code examples showcasing how to implement this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to build a page like [this](https://ui.shadcn.com/themes) ?

Comment: @PinalTilva I examined the code of that page, and it seems to load all the themes (default and new-york) simultaneously, then displays one of the two. However, the programming logic is duplicated. I aim to have a standardized code from which a mechanism can be implemented to select the theme dynamically.

Comment: But you have to set css variable for every themes manually, is it fine?